# What is a "local Git client"

Tags: git, client

I'm fairly new to git and Githab. I was asked by the Github system to review a PR. For one of the changed files I had the message
"... not shown because the diff is too large. Please use a local Git client to view these changes."
The phrase "local Git client" means nothing to me. Can someone please give me examples of "local Git clients"?

Comment: Well one would be... `git`.

Answer (score 1):

A git local client is the `git` command line tool or, if you prefer, one of the tools listed at https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis .

One of the most used and user friendly is [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/).